# MS Project: Continuous line after task with no successor in Gantt chart

Tags: microsoft-project, gantt

In my project Gantt Chart, I see a continuous line following any task bar or summary bar that does not have a successor.

[image]

In so many years of using MS Project, this is the first time I see this. What is it and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out that a style was somehow defined for slack. Deleting that style removed the horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the definitions of the Gantt bar styles (see image below).  Go through the list  to see which one matches this formatting. Modify/delete bar style(s) as desired.

[image: Gantt chart Bar Styles dialog box]

Note: To view the bar styles, right-click in the Gantt chart area and select Bar Styles.